# html 5 и тег audio (1 плеер и треки на странице)

Tags: php, javascript, html5, аудио

Хочу сделать 1 плеер сверху страницы и ниже будут MP3 файлы с ссылками на них.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки рядом с ссылками, ссылка передавалась бы в плеер и начинал проигрываться трек.

Подскажите, как и чем это всё дело сделать.

Comment: Покажите, что вам уже удалось сделать.

Comment: Удалось мне сделать только много плееров на каждой ссылке :(
Пример вот: https://forum.ideah.ru/search/Tata+Simonyan

Тут и на Flash есть такое ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```js
var tracks=[ //urls of mp3s
 "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d1t05.mp3",
 "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d2t02.mp3",
 "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d2t03.mp3",
 "https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d1t10.mp3"
];

var audioEl = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){      
        loadAudio(this.dataset.id - 1, true);
    });
}

function loadAudio(id, autoplay = false) {
    audioEl.preload=true;
    audioEl.controls=true;
    audioEl.src=tracks[id];
    if (autoplay)
     audioEl.play();
}

loadAudio(0);
```

```html
<button data-id="1">трек 1</button>
<button data-id="2">трек 2</button>
<button data-id="3">трек 3</button>
<button data-id="4">трек 4</button>
<audio src="">2</audio>
```

Вместо массива и атрибутов `data-id`, можно ссылки поместить в `data-audiourl` и брать ссылку оттуда и вставлять в трек.

Смысл в том, чтоб брать их из элемента и вставлять в атрибут `src` элемента `audio`, а потом запускать его или не запускать и управлять им, как захочется

---

Пример сразу с ссылками в кнопках

```js
var audioEl = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){      
        loadAudio(this.dataset.url, true);
    });
}

function loadAudio(url, autoplay = false) {
    audioEl.preload=true;
    audioEl.controls=true;
    audioEl.src=url;
    if (autoplay)
     audioEl.play();
}

loadAudio(buttons[0].dataset.url);
```

```html
 
<button data-url="https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d1t05.mp3">трек 1</button>
<button data-url="https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d2t02.mp3">трек 2</button>
<button data-url="https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d2t03.mp3">трек 3</button>
<button data-url="https://archive.org/download/tsp1997-01-24.AT.TC-D5M.flac16/tsp1997-01-24d1t10.mp3">трек 4</button>
<audio src=""></audio>
```